# Diffusion transient term dependent on a different variable

Tags: python, fipy

This is more of a general question about how to represent a diffusion equation where the transient term is dependent on a different variable. For example, if i needed to represent this equation in FiPy,
∂c/∂t=∇D∇T, where c and T are different variables needed to be solved how would I go about representing that. Hopefully that is enough information to answer my question.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It won't solve particularly efficiently, but you'd just write it explicitly:

```py
eq = (fp.TransientTerm(var=c) == (D * T.faceGrad).divergence)
```

Presumably, you have another equation for the evolution of `T`, in which case you might be able to couple your equations to some advantage.